Proxy squid server can't load youtube video
I have this big question about my proxy server!
I made this proxy server using squid and squidguard on ubuntu 22.04, everything works fine (blacklist works), except the fact that when I try to play a video on youtube, the video starts to load and it never stops...
I've noticed something strage too with ookla speed test: when I run the speed test, it starts and never goes further, it doesn't even tell me the speed of my connection...
Do you know what could be the problem?
Thank you for the answers!
